# Regex dot operator in Java seems to always work greedy

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to fetch first paragraph content from HTML snippet... nothing easier, huh? But for some reason, `.*?` operator seems to work greedy:

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<p(?: [^>]*)?>(.*?)</p>", Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher match = regex.matcher("<p class=\"baz\">foo</p> <p>bar</p>");
        System.out.println(match.matches());
        System.out.println(match.group(1));
    }
}
```

I expect to match just the content of the first paragraph (`foo`), but here is the result:

```
$ javac test.java && java test
true
foo</p> <p>bar
```

Any reason why the `.*?` continues to match after first `</p>`?

Comment: it works here https://regex101.com/r/oC3qA3/5

Comment: Try replacing `System.out.println(match.matches());` with `System.out.println(match.find());`

Comment: @npinti Why do you suggest that?

Comment: Obligatory comment: have you considered using an DOM parser to achieve this?

Comment: @Duncan: `matches()` tries to match the entire string. `find()` will find the first match and continue from there.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I know the regex works, that's why I use it, it worked fine in other environments (PHP, JavaScript). But not in Java :O.

Comment: @Duncan DOM would be kind of overkill here I think... But can be the only way if this one won't work :(.

Comment: The dot by itself is not greedy; it will always match one, and only one, character. It is the quantifiers you use which may, or may not, be greedy, or even possessive (`*+`, `++` etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained by npinti [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030982/regex-dot-operator-in-java-seems-to-always-work-greedy/29031291#comment46303077_29030982), the problem is caused by calling `match.match()`. This attempts to match your pattern against the *entire* input string. It only succeeds if the regex engine finds some way to express your string as an instance of your pattern. The only way to achieve this is for it to match `(.*?)` against `foo</p> <p>bar`.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. The easiest is to switch to `match.find()`. This finds the first match of your pattern within the string. Since there is no requirement for the whole string to match, the non-greedy quantifier ensures you get `foo` as required.
2. Adjust your pattern to match the whole string. I.e. `"<p(?: [^>]*)?>(.*?)</p>.*"`.

---

Inevitably, however, these "simple" plans to parse some HTML [grow more and more unwieldy as requirements change](http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/). It really is quite simple to parse HTML with something like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/). Switch to that now and don't look back. Look how easy it is:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment("<p class=\"baz\">foo</p> <p>bar</p>");
Elements paragraphs = doc.getElementsByTag("p");

if (paragraphs.size() > 0) {
  System.out.println(paragraphs.get(0).text());
}
```

Prints: `foo`.

Comment: Thank you for all of the hints, will investigate JSoup, but for now will just fix the code with `find()`.

Comment: @RafałWrzeszcz: Stick to JSoup as per the suggestion. Will save you a lot of trouble int he future.

Comment: @RafałWrzeszcz I've added a JSoup example. It's so much easier than regular expressions...

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for not posting this earlier, did not have an access to a Java environment.

The problem is that `matches()` will try to match the *entire* string. Meaning that it will implicitly add `^` and `$`. Replacing `matches()` with `find()` should fix the issue:

```
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<p(?: [^>]*)?>(.*?)</p>", Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher match = regex.matcher("<p class=\"baz\">foo</p> <p>bar</p>");
    System.out.println(match.find());
    System.out.println(match.group(1));
```

Yields:

```
true
foo
```

Comment: Ahah, I wasn't sure you would post an answer. I'll leave mine, since it has some more details, but up-vote from me for solving the problem!

Comment: @Duncan: Your answer is better because you promote `JSoup` (how you should actually tackle HTML parsing). Got upvote from me.